# Weblogic load balancing and request re-routing to another server

Tags: weblogic, load-balancing

I'm totally new to clustering and load balancing.

What I'm trying to do is "Deploy Application on a Cluster which contains 2 managed servers. Now, If one of the managed server goes down, request should be redirected to another server which is Up."

For Example:
I've 2 managed servers (M1:7021 and M2:7022)
And I've a Cluster C1 having M1 and M2.
And I've an Application App1 deployed on C1 and a Data Source deployed on C1.
Application App1 is working fine.
The way through which I'm accessing application is:
http://10.184.111.11:7021/App1/
AND
http://10.184.111.11:7022/App1/

Now, Suppose if M1(7021) goes down, and request is coming like 
:7021/App1/
Then, it should be redirected to :7022/App1/

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need a load balancer (or a [software equivalent](http://www.inlab.de/articles/free-and-open-source-load-balancing-software-and-projects.html)) to sit above the weblogic servers and direct traffic down to those servers.

The idea being that you access your application on http://loadBalancer.com/App and then the Load Balancer forwards your request onto either one of weblogic servers.  Meanwhile in the background the load balancer is continually performing health checks on the two weblogic servers to see if they are running.

In the event that one of the weblogic servers go down, the load balancer will mark it as inactive and forward all traffic to the weblogic server still running.  Once the failed weblogic server has come back online the load balancer will begin routing traffic back through it.

Comment: Hi Garreth, do you mean clusters as load balancer?
Actually, I was thinking that A cluster (having two managed servers) will give me a single link which I'll use to access the application and will do load balancing internally. But instead, it gave me two links with two different ports.

Comment: I don't believe WebLogic does any internal Load Balancing, for that you must have some Load Balancer.  You could have something as simple as the an apache server using the weblogic plugin as mentioned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2109421/4473858) on the topic.

Comment: You do need a proxy server that will redirect traffic to either one of the two cluster nodes according to their availability and the load balancing algorithm.
Please consult this document for more info about configuring the WebLogic proxy plug-in (mod_wl_ohs) with Oracle HTTP Server:
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/PLGWL/oracle.htm

Comment: Thanks for replies.
I did load balancing through Fusion middleware for weblogic clusters. Reference Link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13709/setup.htm#CLUST466

Answer (score 1):

@Garreth Well, in fact WebLogic DOES provide [an internal load balancer](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/12/13/httpclusterservlet-configuration-weblogic-server-acting-as-a-proxy/). You are supposed to use OHS or Apache for load balancing in production environments, but for development, `httpclusterservlet` works great.